# Extracting values from anyobject dictionary into array

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, option-type

My other question was marked as being identical to another but it didn't answer the problem I was having.

Here is the code:

```
if status == "OK" {


    self.selectedRoute = (dictionary["routes"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>)[0]
    self.overviewPolyline = self.selectedRoute["overview_polyline"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

    let legs = self.selectedRoute["legs"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>
    let steps = legs[0]["steps"]!

    for i in 0...steps.count - 1 {
        let step_coordinate = steps[i]["start_location"]!
        print(step_coordinate!["lat"]!!)

    }

}
```

The print statement gives this result

```
40.7609205
40.7640121
40.7595325
40.7501637
40.7481923
40.7393448
40.7252038
40.7225337
40.718295
```

but if I swap the print statement out to grab the values and put them in an array I get the fatal error: found nil.

Can someone explain why this is the case? How can I grab these values if not through a for loop?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and try not to use `as!` and other force-unwrapping operations. Instead you should properly test and unwrap `Optional` values. Force-unwrapping can lead to nasty, hard-to-find, runtime exceptions. Also, try to format your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `for i in 0...steps.count - 1` can just be: `for i in 0..<steps.count`. Even better, use: `for step in steps { //use step rather than steps[i]`

Comment: @ColGraff You're right thanks. I'll try to avoid doing it in the future. I'm not sure how to adjust the example because I'm just looking for a way to store the values that I've shown above that are coming from step_coordinate["lat"]. I've tried to treat it like an array and it fails so I'm not sure how to grab them.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I tried to do that originally but I got the error type AnyObject does not conform to protocol SequenceType. Since it worked using index iteration I just left it that way.

Comment: Well yeah, you'd have to cast it to an Array or SequenceType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a cleaner version of your code.

Rules:

1. Don't force unwrap anything!
2. Optionally cast values coming from `[NSObject: AnyObject]` lookups.
3. Use `guard` statements and `if let` to safely unwrap optionals.
4. Don't index arrays that might be empty without checking first.

---

```
if status == "OK" {
    guard let routes = dictionary["routes"] as? [[NSObject: AnyObject]] else { return }
    self.selectedRoute = routes.first ?? [:]

    self.overviewPolyline = self.selectedRoute["overview_polyline"] as? [NSObject: AnyObject] ?? [:]

    guard let legs = self.selectedRoute["legs"] as? [[NSObject: AnyObject]] else { return }

    let firstleg = legs.first ?? [:]
    guard let steps = firstleg["steps"] as? [[NSObject: AnyObject]] else { return }

    for step in steps {
        if let step_coordinate = step["start_location"] as? [NSObject: AnyObject] {
            if let lat = step_coordinate["lat"] as? Double {
                print(lat)

                // append lat to array of lats
                lats.append(lat)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much this is exactly what I needed. The cleaned up code let me access the variables much more easily. Cheers.